# Second line of first verse in Sibelius

Tags: sibelius

Is there any quick way to select the second line of the first verse in Sibelius 7? I'm having to go through the output of photoscore by hand and select and move that line to the second verse place for long songs this takes forever.

Answer (score 2):

**There's a Sibelius plugin for that**

Bob Zawalich has written a plugin for this purpose. It is called *Verse Styles for Lyrics*. You can download it here.

http://www.sibelius.com/download/plugins/index.html?plugin=290

Comment: Photoscore tends to put all lyrics in 'Lyrics Line 1' text style, but position them apart.  A Reset Position will put them all on top of each other.

You need to apply the Text Styles 'Lyrics Line 2', 'Lyrics Line 3' etc. to each line.  Yes, Bob's plugin can help a lot in doing this.